# H1B Visa holder travel to Niagara Passing through Canada Via Road

Tags: usa, transit, canada, indian-citizens

I am H1B visa holder working in Illinois USA . My wife an son have H4 Visa and my mom has a visitor visa for USA. All of us have Indian citizenship. I want to travel by road to Niagara Falls from Illinois, USA via Canada. I might need to halt for a night maybe in US or Canada (definitely not exceeding 48 hours in Canada) if required by my mom and son.

I am also planning to take the same route while coming back to Illinois, USA.

What kind of visa is required ?

Comment: The  aspect of this question which the current answer doesn't address and which I couldn't find any answer to online is transit vs tourist visas. Would for example someone traveling to the US side of niagra falls via Canada be regarded as a legitimate transit case or not.

Comment: @PeterGreen Canadian transit visas are only valid for travel where you enter and leave Canada by air.

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of the method of entry you will need a visa.

You can check your eligibility on the [CIC Website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) as well as apply online for it.

Generally speaking if you're driving on the road 4 hours that you spend in Canada doesn't warrant needing to stay anywhere along the route.  it is also possible that depending on where you're driving from in Illinois your best route to Niagara Falls may not be through Canada.

Comment: Going south of Lake Erie adds about 45mins to the journey from Chicago.

Comment: @DJClayworth Starting from Metropolis, IL doesn't, same for East St. Louis.

Comment: His desired destination may be Niagara Falls, Ontario no matter which side of Lake Erie he travels. I would assume this if the trip is for sightseeing since that side of the river has more going on.

Comment: @Dennis Again.  The issue was about getting there be it on US or Canadian side of the Falls but still Illinois is a big state and driving from the northern parts differs to doing so from the southern part of the state while you end up at the same destination.  So yes the view from Canadian side is better but getting there may only involve crossing border at Rainbow Bridge.

Comment: @Karlson, that's true, just saying that the entry requirements crossing the Rainbow bridge for a several hour stay are the same as those for crossing at Detroit for a several day stay, so if they're traveling for tourism they might want visas regardless of the route. If the destination is just Niagara Falls, NY, however, then never mind.

Comment: @Dennis If the intention is to go through Canada to get to Niagara Falls, NY and watch the falls from US side I'd close that question on general principal!

Comment: Thanks Every one for their advice .  I have any way ruled out the possibility of stay in Canada for a night  and have taken a room on US side. Biggest reason I wanted to pass via Canada was lesser distance  I'll be close to Detroit for some official reason just before the trip  So I was thinking of taking advantage of it so I'll have to travel lesser distance.